# Asynchronous Socket

Tags: python, sockets

How do I connect with multiple clients? Once connected with multiple clients how do I receive individual data from each? From what I know I need to use something called "Asyncore". How do I implement this?

Client Class

```
import socket
class Client():
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.port = 5000

        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))
        self.s.send(str.encode(input("What is your name ")))

x = Client()
```

Host Class

```
import socket
class Host():
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.port = 5000

        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.s.listen(5)
        self.c, self.addr = self.s.accept()
        print("User from " + str(self.addr) + " has connected")
        while True:
            data = self.c.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break

            print(str(self.addr) +" name is " + data.decode("utf-8"))
            #c.send(str.encode(whatever))
        self.c.close()

x = Host()
```

Comment: do you mean asyncio? https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html asyncore has been replaces by asyncio *Note This module exists for backwards compatibility only. For new code we recommend using asyncio.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this one? `asyncore`

Here is the link where you can find all the info related to async socket handler

https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html

EDIT: dano comment is great too

Enjoy

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. I have read through the documentation but don't seem to be able to understand how asyncore can handle multiple clients.

Comment: Maybe this helps more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605083/python-asyncore-keep-track-of-clients ;)

Comment: I'd recommend using [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) instead of `asyncore`, if Python 3 is an option. If it's not, you can use [`trollius`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trollius), which is a backport of `asyncio` to Python 2.x

Comment: Thanks dano. If you have used some of this, then dano's answer is the good one. I only was trying and found some info 'Googling' the right words :P