# Python Websockets - Problem with await in class

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

Hi I'm writing an simple video chat app server and I run into a problem where I can't await a function `send_to_all()` in Room class. Im new to asyncio and I don't know how should I've done it.

I've tried using threading and using some sort of asyncio thing that i found online all of that didn't work

```
class Room:
     def __init__(self,_id,owner):
          self.owner = owner
          self.id = _id
          self.participants = []
          
          print("[DEBUG] New room has been created")
          
     async def send_msg_to_all(self, message):
          print("[DEBUG] Sending message")
          for participant in self.participants:
               await participant.conn.send(message)
```

After running code above I get RuntimeError

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Room.send_msg_to_all' was never awaited
  self.send_msg_to_all(str(serialized_partipants_info))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: you can only await async functions, and you can't await a function multiple times in a loop. that's two things i can see that are wrong. but you should also post your error log.

Comment: ohh i forgot thanks for reminding me

Comment: these are just warnings, not errors.

Comment: I know but the problem is that participant.conn.send(message) line must be awaited because of websockets module requirements

Comment: is participant.conn.send an async function or it's just a normal function?

Comment: I checked python websockets github and i dont think it is async function because participant.conn is a normal websocket connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) you can't await just any normal functions:

> We say that an object is an awaitable object if it can be used in an await expression. There are three main types of awaitable objects: coroutines, Tasks, and Futures

you have to use a library that is created with async capabilities something like [asyncore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222534/asynchronous-socket).
keep in mind that you can't await an already awaited async call.
I didn't use asyncore package myself so you have to read about its usage. but in a general situation you have to define separate async functions and then gather them like this:

```
async def async_method1(*args):
  #do your thing

async def async_method1(*args):
  #do your thing

async def async_method1(*args):
  #do your thing

async def all_my_calls(*args):
  reslist = await asyncio.gather(
        async_method1(*args),
        async_method2(*args),
        async_method3(*args))
  # do stuff with your reslist


asyncio.run(all_my_calls(*args))
```

please keep in mind, depending on your logic, you might not need any input `*args` or output `reslist`. I just included them in my code so you'll know how to pass arguments and process the results **if you need to**.

**EDIT**:

as Tomek Pulkiewicz already mentioned in the comments asyncore is only used for normal sockets. if you want to use async web-sockets use [asyncore-wsgi](https://pypi.org/project/asyncore-wsgi/)

Comment: Ok now i understand but i don't really know how to implement this in my code. Should my reslist look like this reslist = await asyncio.gather( x.conn.send(message) for x in self.participants)   or how PS:thanks for the answer

Comment: @TomekPulkiewicz I didn't use the asyncore myself, maybe you should dig into that. but usually you should define a different async function for each one. each of of the async methods should be defined separately. I'll add their definition to my code.

Comment: Ohh thanks this is the post i was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222534/asynchronous-socket.

Comment: Ohh but I think it's only for normal sockets, not WebSockets. But I found a library that uses WebSockets https://pypi.org/project/asyncore-wsgi/ Thanks for setting my track

Comment: @TomekPulkiewicz i'll add the library you found to my answer for anyone else who might need it then, thanks :)