# How can i send socket asynchronously?

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous

this is my code

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8001))

message = json.dumps({
                "wave-file": '/home/s41140/projects/python/asynchronous/wav/converted_1635659734733081.wav',
                "text": "hello".upper(),
            }) + '\n'

logging.info('Just before sending to tcp socket, message: {}'
             .format(message))
# send request
s.sendall(message.encode())

# read response
sockfile = s.makefile(mode='r')
line = sockfile.readline()
print(line)
```

this code is sync, I want to send data and get response async
Thanks for your helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python simple socket client/server using asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506460/python-simple-socket-client-server-using-asyncio)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222534/asynchronous-socket